# How do you add the value of a variable instead of the variable to a mouseclick event in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, variables

I decided that I'd try creating a simple programming language. Everything's working so far except for one thing - executing code by clicking on a GUI element. This is the line of code responsible for adding the event to a button:

```
btn[x].MouseClick += (sender, e) => runAct(act_alloc, sender, e);
```

The problem here is that the runAct(); void requires an ID (act_alloc) to know what code to run, but act_alloc changes every time a new action for a GUI element is created, but I need the MouseClick event to be a constant number, for example:

```
btn[0].MouseClick += (sender, e) => runAct(2, sender, e);
```

I need to get the value of the `act_alloc` variable at the time of adding the event to the element, but just the value, not the variable itself - I don't want the MouseClick event to use a different ID (the value of `act_alloc` at the time the element is clicked), I want the MouseClick event to use the same ID every time (the value of `act_alloc` at the time the element's MouseClick event is assigned to `runAct(...)`.

The app just reads code from a file line by line. The `act_alloc` integer gets increased by 1 every time a MouseClick event is added to a GUI element.

The `runAct` void requires `int id, object sender, EventArgs e`. The last two are there just so that it can be used as a MouseClick. When some code gets added from the code file to the element's MouseClick event, it gets stored in a String[1024,128] - [Event ID, code (<=127 lines)]. This is the runAct void:

```
public void runAct(int id, object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int x = 1; x <= Convert.ToInt32(act[id, 0]); x++)
        runCode(act[id, x].Split(';'));
}
```

`act` is the String[,] in which code is stored. The first string is always the amount of lines stored, which gets converted into an integer so that it won't just call `runCode` over and over again without any code to run. The `runCode` void does what it's called - runs a line of code. One of those can be `act;(gui_element);`, which means that all following code gets stored in the act string[,]. This stops at a `endact;` line. After the code is stored in the string[,] (`act[act_alloc, line]`), `act_alloc` gets increased by 1 so that the app's ready to store some more code in the string[,].

This is the code that adds a MouseClick event to a GUI element:

```
case "act": //add code to an element
    bool wa = true; //keep looping
    int ln = 1; //line number
    while (wa) //loop for adding more code
    {
        string actstr = vars(sr.ReadLine()); //read the next line
        if (actstr == "endact;") //was that all the code?
        {
            wa = false; //stop the loop
        }
        else
        {
            act[act_alloc, ln] = actstr; //store the line
            ln++; //next line
        }
    }
    ln--; //decrease ln by 1 to make sure runAct runs the correct amount of times
    act[act_alloc, 0] = ln.ToString(); //the amount of lines stored gets saved
    switch (cmd[2]) //what GUI element is this code for?
    {
        case "text": //a label
            for (int x = 0; x < label_alloc; x++) //cycle through all the labels
                if (labels[x].Name == cmd[3]) //does the label name match?
                    labels[x].MouseClick += (sender, e) => runAct(act_alloc, sender, e); //add the event
            break;
            case "btn": //a button
                for (int x = 0; x < btn_alloc; x++) //cycle through all the buttons
                    if (btn[x].Name == cmd[3]) //does the button name match?
                        btn[x].MouseClick += (sender, e) => runAct(act_alloc, sender, e); //add the event
            break;
    }
    act_alloc++; //get ready for storing more code
    break;
```

If that's still not enough info, please let me know.

Comment: Without more information about runAct and act_alloc, it will be very difficult for us to help you.

Comment: How about copying the value of `act_alloc` right before that line, and then use that local variable in `runAct(localvariable, sender, e)`? (I'm not certain that your problem is actually there in the first place though)

Comment: Sorry for not providing enough info, should be okay now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How about copying the value of act_alloc right before that line, and then use that local variable in runAct(localvariable, sender, e)? (I'm not certain that your problem is actually there in the first place though)
>
> – lucidbrot

That actually solved my problem, thank you!
I just added a new int right before adding the MouseClick event to the element:

```
act[act_alloc, 0] = ln.ToString();
int eid = act_alloc;
switch (cmd[2])
{
    case "text":
        for (int x = 0; x < label_alloc; x++)
            if (labels[x].Name == cmd[3])
                labels[x].MouseClick += (sender, e) => runAct(eid, sender, e);
        break;
    case "btn":
        for (int x = 0; x < btn_alloc; x++)
            if (btn[x].Name == cmd[3])
                btn[x].MouseClick += (sender, e) => runAct(eid, sender, e);
        break;
}
act_alloc++;
```